# EdittText Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am using EditText control in android, and I want to know if there is any way get the defaul string of the control(I mean the one that is in String.xml).

I use this when i want to modify its string.

```
e.setText( e.getText().toString + "something").
```

Now, the problem is that sometimes i get unnecessary information like :

```
" Name: JhonName: JhonName: JhonName: JhonName: Jhon "
```

When I just wanna show: 
          " Name: Jhon "

If i didnt explain properly, let me know :)

Comment: Add a couple of Log statements and check your LogCat.  Log.i("value", e.getText().toString()); and Log.i("value", e.getText().toString() + "something"); Log.i("value", getString(R.string.the_name_of_your_string_to_get_from_strings_dot_xml));

Comment: you want to modify or replace the string in the edit text?

Comment: I would recommend you show the chunk of code that uses it to see what you are doing. I think I understand what you are doing though. You want to use the String that is default on it. Then change it, right? If not, then you should probably re-explain what you are trying to do lol

Answer (score 0):

`e.getText().toString()` is return the string of your EditText....
now for the first time when you execute your code ..the above method will not return anything.. that's why your EditText will like "Name: John"..ok

when second time this code executes... the above method will return "Name: John"
and after that you adding "Something" so that why it happens...

just replace you code with this...

```
e.setText("something")
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to write editText.setText(editText.getText().toString()+"something"), this will definately add "something" in the previous string. You should only write editText.setText("Something"), if you want only to print "something".

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you know about Tag and Hint attributes of edit text. You can set tag and hint in both the ways XML as well as Java. So set the default (prefix) value in hint, append that value whenever you are settext to edit text.

for ex.:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Name : " />


e.setText(e.getHint() + "John");
```